# Auto populated Text box values in php

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to create a dynamic page based on user's input. Here is a piece of code that i am struck with.

There, is a section in which I am trying to ask the user's their available house configurations, such as 1 BHK, 2BHK ... etc.. However, i have a code that is currently doing the job partially.

```
<div id="mydiv">
        <input type="checkbox" name="1 RK Apartment" id="1 RK Apartment" value="1 RK" onClick="dynInput(this);"/> 1 RK Apartment<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="1 BHK Apartment" id="1 BHK Apartment" value="1 BHK" onClick="dynInput(this);" /> 1 BHK Apartment<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="1.5 BHK Apartment" id="1.5 BHK Apartment" value="1.5 BHK" onClick="dynInput(this);" /> 1.5 BHK Apartment<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="2 BHK Apartment" id="2 BHK Apartment" value="2 BHK" onClick="dynInput(this);" /> 2 BHK Apartment<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="2.5 BHK Apartment" id="2.5 BHK Apartment" value="2.5 BHK" onClick="dynInput(this);" /> 2.5 BHK Apartment<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="3 BHK Apartment" id="3 BHK Apartment" value="3 BHK" onClick="dynInput(this);" /> 3 BHK Apartment<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="3.5 BHK Apartment" id="3.5 BHK Apartment" value="3.5 BHK" onClick="dynInput(this);" /> 3.5 BHK Apartment <br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="4 BHK Apartment" id="4 BHK Apartment" value="4 BHK" onClick="dynInput(this);" /> 4 BHK Apartment <br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="4+ BHK Apartment" id="4+ BHK Apartment" value="4+ BHK" onClick="dynInput(this);" /> 4+ BHK Apartment <br />

        <textarea id="txtValue" name="config"></textarea>
     </div>   
     </tr>
   <tr valign="baseline"> 
    <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Configuration Sizes</td>
    <td><textarea name="configsize" class="form-control"></textarea><br />
    <p id="insertinputs"></p></td>
   </tr>
```

And here is the Jquery for the same:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function dynInput(cbox) {
      if (cbox.checked) {
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        var input1 = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        var div1 = document.createElement("div");
        div.id = cbox.name;
        div.innerHTML = "Enter Max Size of " + cbox.name;
        div1.innerHTML = "Enter Min Size of " + cbox.name;
        div.appendChild(input);
        div.appendChild(input1);
        document.getElementById("insertinputs").appendChild(div); 
        document.getElementById("insertinputs").appendChild(div1);
      } else {
        document.getElementById(cbox.name).remove();
      }
    }
    </script>
```

I need a procedure or method to capture all the data entered and have them echoed in a text area or text box.. with csv format. where further processing can be done..

When ever an user selects a checkbox, there are two dynamic textboxs that are being generated.However, I am unable to do it.

Comment: Well the question here is, what are you expecting? And what are you getting? Also why tag it as php when you are not using any php?